# How to do strict LocalDate parsing in js-joda?

Tags: javascript, jsr310, js-joda

I'm trying to parse a [`LocalDate`](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/js-joda/js-joda/class/src/LocalDate.js~LocalDate.html) from a `String` using strict resolution in [`js-joda`](http://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/) (version 1.1.1). I don't want to accept inputs that aren't valid dates, like `2016-05-32`. But I just don't get it.

My code is:

```
formatter = (new JSJoda.DateTimeFormatterBuilder)
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .toFormatter(JSJoda.ResolverStyle.STRICT);

JSJoda.LocalDate.parse("2016-05-10", formatter);
```

and the error:

```
Text '2016-05-10' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from
TemporalAccessor: [object Object], type DateTimeBuilder: 2016-05-10,
at index: 0
```

The same code with `ResolverStyle.LENIENT` or `ResolverStyle.SMART` works as it's expected for this modes.

```
formatter = (new JSJoda.DateTimeFormatterBuilder)
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .toFormatter(JSJoda.ResolverStyle.LENIENT);

JSJoda.LocalDate.parse("2016-05-32", formatter); // result 2016-06-01
```

How can I use strict resolution in [`js-joda`](http://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/)?

[JS Demo](https://tonicdev.com/5730e524abbf001200bb88da/5730e573abbf001200bb88ee)

*Update*:

However the [js-joda DateTimeFormatter API](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/js-joda/js-joda/class/src/format/DateTimeFormatter.js~DateTimeFormatter.html#static-method-ofPattern) does not mention this option, the pattern `uuuu-MM-dd` proposed by @JodaStephen works fine. [Working Js Demo](https://tonicdev.com/5731b4c2ac945f1100995d56/5731b4c2ac945f1100995d57)

[js-joda api](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/js-joda/js-joda/class/src/format/DateTimeFormatter.js~DateTimeFormatter.html#static-method-ofPattern):

```
 |Symbol  |Meaning                     |Presentation      |Examples
 |--------|----------------------------|------------------|---------------
 | G      | era                        | number/text      | 1; 01; AD; Anno Domini
 | y      | year                       | year             | 2004; 04
 | D      | day-of-year                | number           | 189
 | M      | month-of-year              | number/text      | 7; 07; Jul; July; J
```

[Java api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
 Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   G       era                         text              AD; Anno Domini; A
   u       year                        year              2004; 04
   y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
   D       day-of-year                 number            189
```

Comment: In Java you have to use uuuu-MM-dd

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it. It may be usefull to others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern "yyyy-MM-dd" is incomplete in STRICT mode as it does not provide the era. Use the pattern "uuuu-MM-dd" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use the LocalDate.parse function without specifying a formatter.

```
LocalDate.parse('2016-05-10');  // '2016-05-10'

LocalDate.parse('2016-05-32');  // throws a DateTimeParseException
```